# How can I compute the lower and upper bounds of a confidence interval in a linear regression problem?

Tags: regression, self-study, confidence-interval, psychology, mathematica

I am completing a university statistics assignment on the Mathematica program, and this is the initial question:
"The Medical Research Council wanted to evaluate the 
effects of different dosages of a drug that was designed to reduce 
pain in patients.  To test this, they tested 4 levels of the drug.
The different levels were 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3,  micrograms per 
milliliter. The experimenter attempted to recruit 4 patients for each
level of the drug.  Volunteers were randomly assigned to the 
different levels of the drug. After being on that dosage of drug for 
two weeks, patients were asked to rate their pain on a scale of 0 to 
10, where 0 meant no pain at all and 10 meant that they were in 
excruciating pain. Pain judgments are usually normally distributed 
with the variance approximately independent of the mean. Pain 
judgements were collected in private for each patient. (Sometimes 
patients will drop out of a study so the number in each group is not 
always the target number. Analyze the data. Use[Alpha] = 0.05."

This problem has an N=16, and df=14.
I have computed SSX,SSY,SXY, By, Ay,SSE, Sx|y, Sb, t-obtained, Y|xp, and Sy|xp..

Now, it is asking me to compute the lower and upper boundaries of the confidence interval , and also to use an Alpha of 0.01 (different from the alpha stated above).
I have the formula, it is -Talpha/2*Sy|xp, but I am not sure as to how to apply it. I have the "Sy|xp" value, but I do not know how to find the "-Talpha/2" value. If anyone could help to explain this to me, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I forgot to add that Sy|xp =  0.376393

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its wiki.